# GWT Date Picker Format problem when saving a java date through hibernate in postgresql

Tags: java, database, hibernate, gwt, date

I am using Java Date and Hibernate which is then being saved in the database (Postgresql). I am not that good in hibernate

**Part of the Mapping File**

```
<property name="DateOfBirth" type="java.util.Date">
            <column name="DATEOFBIRTH" />
</property>
```

I am using GWT Date picker Short date format i.e. yyyy-MM-dd. I am getting the value from the date picker using

```
View.getUserDateOfBirth().getValue()
```

But when I am saving the date 2010-11-30 into the datebase it is saving it as

```
2010-11-30 00:00:00
```

instead of 2010-11-30

So, I want it to be saved in the database as in this format 2010-11-30??

I have many things such timestamp but i not being able to configure it. I think this part

```
 <property name="DateOfBirth" type="java.util.Date">
                <column name="DATEOFBIRTH" />
    </property>
```

should be changed but I do not know what to change

Comment: What format have you specified in your PostgreSQL database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried just specifying:

```
 <property name="DateOfBirth" type="date">
                <column name="DATEOFBIRTH" />
    </property>
```

Also, further to what pablochan said, I'd check what column type Postgres is using - it should be DATE, which stores dates only.  If it's TIMESTAMP, then it will store the both date and time.

Comment: ya i think that was the problem timestamp but i don't want to do anything at the level of database, i want to work only with java and hibernate and have everything generated with hibernate

Comment: when using type as date only we get the error org.hibernate.MappingException: Could not determine type for: Date, at table: PERSONALUSER, for columns: [org.hibernate.mapping.Column(DATEOFBIRTH)]

Comment: Sorry the date works, I was getting the above error because i put the type as type="Date" which should have been type="date", the case matters, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If the `DATEOFBIRTH` column is a Date then this is correct and your not storing time information, but you have to remember that `java.util.Date` has time information (so it's like a timestamp) and when you read the date from the database the time will be set to 00:00:00 since that data was truncated when storing in the database.

Comment: So, is it possible to get only the date value

Comment: You are getting just the date. You can format the output with the DateFormat class so the time part doesn't show.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont want time info, you can use java.sql.Date instead of java.util.Date.

Answer (score 0):

Britishmuu answer is correct, you should use the `type` attribute to specify the datatype you want Hibernate to generate in your database, not the datatype used by Java to hold this value.

This configuration:

```
<property name="DateOfBirth" type="date">
     <column name="DATEOFBIRTH" />
</property>
```

will tell Hibernate to generate a column named DATEOFBIRTH with a date type :

```
CREATE TABLE "User"
(
  "DATEOFBIRTH" date
)
```

The value will then be stored in your database as 2010-11-30